# When hitting concurrent requests using jmeter, deadlock exceptions occurred?

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Here is the C# code which is using [Ambient Context](https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) with the [EF6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6)

```
 public async Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(RefreshToken refreshToken)
    {
        using (var dbContextScope = _dbContextScopeFactory.Create())
        {
            _refreshTokenRepository.Delete(refreshToken);
            return await dbContextScope.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
    }
```

Getting the following exception

```
Exception Source: EntityFramework   Inner Exception:  Transaction (Process ID 
89) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen 
as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

This error is occurring only when concurrent requests are there using JMeter

Comment: Before we continue, do you understand what a database deadlock is? What database are you using?

Comment: congratulations! your performance testing have found a bug, not otherwise reproducible. Nothing wrong with your test in that regard.

Comment: @mjwills, You are right!! this is database deadlock error. I will look into that direction now. Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Are there any ways to prevent these database deadlocks?